# Detecting 404 error page Laravel 4.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to add a class to body if the page is an error page -- specifically 404.

Similar to

```
{{ Request::is('my-page') ? 'newclass' : '' }}
```

Is there any way to detect a specific error page?

My route:

```
App::missing(function($exception) {
   return Response::view('error-404', array(), 404);
});
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you're trying to do? `App::missing` would seem to cover it.

Comment: Sure thing. I've updated the question to be more specific.

Comment: Thanks, that makes what you're trying to do a lot clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the view name to each (or a specific) view as a variable. For Laravel 4 you can do this in the filters.php:

```
View::composer('*', function($view){
    View::share('name_of_view', $view->getName());
});
```

Then you can do `{{ ($name_of_view == "error-404") ? 'newclass' : '' }}` in your views.